# Can more pushed keys be read?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am curious if some game like Mortal Kombat can be written in browser.

The only problem I see is reading more than three pushed keys. I tried this, but three keys pushed together seems to be the limit: more keys are ignored.

```
var keytrap = document.getElementById("keytrap");
var keys = {};
keytrap.focus();

function info() {
    var nfo = document.getElementById("info");
    nfo.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i in keys) if(keys[i]) nfo.innerHTML+= i;
}

keytrap.onkeydown = function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = true; info(); }
keytrap.onkeyup = function(e) { keys[e.keyCode] = false; info(); }
```

See [the fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/jd3je/2/).

I'd like to read at least six keys simultaneously. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Your approach looks good - it detects more than three keys for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE9.

Comment: You might get limited by the hardware where your game is running. Some keyboards themselves won't report more than a certain amount of keys.

Comment: @Adam what hardware did you used then?

Comment: @frozenkoi: I can confirm that. It happens in all games if you have a bad keyboard.

Comment: I was able to use your fiddle and get 6 keys pressed okay...  MacBook Pro mid-2012 model.

Comment: Here it is working, but I noticed it stop detecting all keys if the Key begins to repeat. Chome 30.0.1599.101 m. Keyboard, Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 800

Comment: Try to increase the Operating system time for repeat keys, just to see that it interferes on the textbox. Try to use your key detection on the html document body, not on a Text Box.

Comment: @Tony: no effect. It is also strange that "WER" is captured together on my notebook, but "ERT" not. It really seems to be a pure HW issue.

Comment: Here's a question on Arquade that covers this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @frozenkoi comments, it is pure hardware issue. If anyone runs into the same problem, see the @Qantas94Heavy's comment to my question to see the list of good keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

This library: [keypress](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/) is maybe the solution, I didn't try with an old keyboard! But there are special combos and Special "counting" combos features.